Fano manifold with vanishing cohomologies of the tangent bundle
Does there exist a projective Fano Manifold $X$ of Picard number one such that $H^i(TX)= 0$ for all $i$, where $TX$ denotes the tangent bundles of $X$ ? If yes, then does there exist any classification of such Fano manifolds ?

Quintic del Pezzo surfaces work, except they have higher Picard rank.  Maybe an appropriate linear section of a Grassmannian such that the dimension of the section is at least three . . .

@JasonStarr Tricky, but maybe not impossible, to make a linear section of a Grassmanian work, since this condition guarantees that the deformation space is trivial. I guess the dimension of the deformation space of a linear section of the Grassmanian of $m$-planes in $n$-space is $\binom{n}{m} - n^2$ which I don't think has a solution.

@WillSawin: The dimension of the deformation space of a linear section depepends on its codimension. If the codimension is $k$, the dimension is $$k\left(\tbinom{n}{m} - k\right) - n^2 + 1.$$ For instance, quintic del Pezzo surfaces are linear sections of $\mathrm{Gr}(2,5)$ of codimension $4$, so $n = 5$, $m = 2$, $k = 4$.

An interesting 4-dimensional example with Picard rank 6 is constructed in https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.16154. And the tools from https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.17003 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2311.17004 allow you to construct Fano varieties as moduli spaces of quiver representations. But again, their Picard rank will be high (but Picard rank 2 is now possible).
